# Почему перестают работать пути при запуске php-скрипта через консоль?

Tags: php

Приветствую. В скрипте есть разные функции, зависящие от внешних файлов(такие как `file_get_contents();`, например). При запуске через браузер всё работает отлично, ни одной ошибки. Но если запустить через консоль, то я получаю множество ошибок "такого файла нет". Пути в скрипте указываются относительные. Файлы, на которые я ссылаюсь, лежат в одном каталоге со скриптом.

Я, конечно, нашел решение:

```
file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) ."\\file.txt");
```

но всё таки интересно понять, почему в браузере работает, а в консоли - нет.

Comment: Не забывайте так же про `__DIR__` константу. Сушествует с версии 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При работе через браузер, текущий путь - это путь, где лежит запрашиваемый скрипт. А при работе через консоль это путь, откуда вызывается интерпретатор PHP